# Integral Involving $(\arcsin x)^3$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Find the integral of $$\int_{0}^{1}8(\arcsin x)^3 dx$$

Okay, so I have substituted $u = \arcsin x$.
I multiplied the integral by $$(1-x^2)^{1/2}/(1-x^2)^{1/2}$$
And then I said that $$\cos u = (1-x^2)^{1/2}$$

And then I basically got the integral of $$u^3 \cos(u) du$$
And then this is integrated three times by integration by parts, yes?

But then, when I plugged it in, I got some very odd numbers.
(This is multiple choice question and I wasn't even close to any of the options...)

Where did I make a mistake?

EDIT:
Or maybe I used the wrong limits? It should be from 0 to pi/4 yes?

Comment: I got $u^3\sin u+3u^2\cos u-6u\sin u-6\cos u$ for the indefinite integral. Is that the same as you got?

Comment: The limits should be from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$, as $\arcsin(1)=\pi/2$

Answer (score 1):

Doing your procedure,
one should obtain:
$$
\int_{u=0}^{u=\frac{\pi}{2}} 8u^3 \cos(u) = 8\left(u(u^2-6)\sin(u)+3(u^2-2)\cos(u)\right) \left. \right|_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}=48-24\pi + \pi^3
$$